# Problems when freeing a dynamically allocated 2d array in C

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, malloc, free

I am desperately trying to free a 2d int array and can't manage to do so.
I guess there's something wrong when i intialize the array?
Could you please help me out?

```
    int rows = 2;
    int cols = 3;
    int *mfields = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int) * rows * cols);
    int **matrix = (int **) malloc(sizeof(int *) * rows);
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        matrix[i] = mfields + i * cols;
        for(int j=0; j<rows;j++) {
            matrix[i][j] = (i+1)*(j+1);
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        free((matrix[i]));
    }
    free(matrix);
```

Thanks in advance,
Christian

Comment: Only free what you malloc, i.e. mfields and matrix.

Comment: what is `mfields` purpose?

Comment: @ryyker: `mfields` allocates memory for the array elements in one complete chunk, and `matrix[i] = mfields + i * cols;` sets the pointer for row `i` to point to the memory for that row. It is correct as written, although creating a matrix as a pointer to pointers into one chunk of allocated memory is only slightly better than creating a matrix as a pointer to pointers to multiple chunks of allocated memory. (A single pointer to a variable-length array is better as long as the target C implementations support it.)

Comment: Christian, Code does 2 allocations and `rows + 1` free calls.  Do you think the number of `malloc()` and `free()` calls should be the same?

Comment: BTW, this is not a _dynamically allocated 2d array_.  It is 2 allocations of 1D arrays.  First is memory for an array of `int` and the 2nd is memory for an array of `int *`.

Comment: BTW you dont **need** the `matrix` array of pointers, it can always be recomputed as `mfields + i * cols` .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two chunks of memory are allocated:

```
int *mfields = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int) * rows * cols);
int **matrix = (int **) malloc(sizeof(int *) * rows);
```

and therefore two chunks of memory should be freed:

```
free(matrix);
free(mfields);
```

Freeing multiple chunks of memory, as this loop does:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        free((matrix[i]));
```

is incorrect, as it passes addresses to `free` that were never returned from `malloc`.

Generally, it is not good to implement matrices as pointers-to-pointers. This prevents the processor from doing load prediction and impairs performance. If the C implementation(s) that will be used with the code support variable length arrays, then it is preferable to simply allocate one chunk of memory:

```
int (*matrix)[cols] = malloc(rows * sizeof *matrix);
```

If variable length array support is not available, then a program should allocate one chunk of memory and use manual calculations to address array elements. While this is may be more work for the programmer, it is better for performance:

```
int *matrix = malloc(rows * cols * sizeof *matrix);
for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
        matrix[i*cols + j] = (i+1) * (j+1);
```

Comment: It might be worthwhile to demonstrate `for( int *row = matrix; row < matrix + rows * cols; row += cols ){ for( int *v = row; v < row + cols; v++ ){ ... }}` YMMV